# Responsive CSS for Samsung Galaxy tablet 2

Tags: android, css, responsive-design

I've recently created a webpage that works fine on computers and smartphones. But when I sent it to my friend, she said her Samsung Galaxy tablet 2 showed the banner in the wrong place among other issues.
In my CSS, I've made rules for these widths:

```
max-width: 479px  
(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)  
(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 995px)
```

Can someone please help me understand where I'm going wrong? I couldn't find any site that would let me test for Tab 2 otherwise I wouldn't have troubled you guys...

Thanks!

Comment: Add some javascript alert on page and to find out the widths for that tablet

Comment: so there is no fixed width for Tab2? that friend is in uni n won't be available for the whole day...

Answer (score 0):

add this meta tag under head tag if it is missing.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: I have this: <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">, is that right?